# Array search algorithms: performance comparison

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, error-handling, search

I'm making a program that compares multi-key sequential search and Interpolation search in a sorted array by the number of array accesses for my assignment.

```
/*
 * A program that compares Multi-key sequential search and Interpolation search in a sorted array by the number of array accesses.
 *
 * TODO:
 *  - make Exceptions with enum/map/static...?
 *  - enable sequence access count?
 *  - complete generate() and the required BTSort
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
/* Utility class. */
class Exception {
protected:
    short code;
    string text;
public:
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Exception& p_exception) {
        return out << p_exception.text;
    }
    void execute() {
        cerr << text;
        exit(code);
    };
};

class IndexOutOfBoundsException     : public Exception { public: IndexOutOfBoundsException()    { text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to access the index outside the bounds of the array!"; code = 1; } };
class IndexOfEmptyFieldException    : public Exception { public: IndexOfEmptyFieldException()   { text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to access the index of an empty field!"; code = 2; } };
class AllocationFailureException    : public Exception { public: AllocationFailureException()   { text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to allocate dynamic memory!"; code = 3; } };
class OpenFileFailureException      : public Exception { public: OpenFileFailureException()     { text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to open a file!"; code = 4; } };
class OpenedFileEmptyException      : public Exception { public: OpenedFileEmptyException()     { text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to read from an empty file!"; code = 5; } };
class ArrayAlreadyExistsException   : public Exception { public: ArrayAlreadyExistsException()  { text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to create an already existing array!"; code = 6; } };
class InvalidArgumentException      : public Exception { public: InvalidArgumentException()     { text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to convert a string to an integer!"; code = 6; } };
class NumberTooLargeException       : public Exception { public: NumberTooLargeException()      { text = "\nERR:    An unsuccessful attempt was made to store an exceedingly large number!"; code = 7; } };
/* Main class. */
class SortedArray {
    int *array;
    int length, capacity;
public:
    SortedArray(int p_capacity) : capacity(p_capacity), length(0) {
        try {
            array = new int[p_capacity];
        }
        catch (bad_alloc) { AllocationFailureException exception; exception.execute();
        }
    }
    int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }
    int getFrom(int i);
    void generate(); // Use BTSort() from dz1p2.cpp to generate a sorted array.
    void loadFromFile(string&);     // In both cases, input is assumed to be ordered, ascending integer array. If input isn't
    void loadFromInput(string&);    // ordered and ascending, it can be sorted with BTSort() used in SortedArray::generate();
    ~SortedArray() {
        if (array) delete array;
    }
};
/* Testing class. */
class TestRecord {
    int accesses;
    unsigned *locations;
    SortedArray array, sequence;
public:
    TestRecord(SortedArray p_array, SortedArray p_sequence) : accesses(0), array(p_array), sequence(p_sequence) {
        int length = sequence.getLength();
        try {
            locations = new unsigned[length];
        }
        catch (bad_alloc) {
            AllocationFailureException exception;
            exception.execute();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            locations[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    int getAccesses() {
        return accesses;
    }
    void resetAccesses() {
        accesses = 0;
    }
    void accessed() {
        accesses++;
    }
    void MultiKeySequentialSearchTest();
    void InterpolationSearchTest();
    ~TestRecord() {
        if (locations) delete locations;
    }
};
/* Main program. */
void main() { // Loads the arrays, tests the search methods and outputs the results.
    //
    return;
}
/* Utility function. */
int readNumber(string& p_text, char& p_delimiter) { // References are used to enable side-effects.
    int integer;
    unsigned *position = new unsigned;
    try {
        integer = stoi(p_text, position);
    }
    catch (invalid_argument) {
        InvalidArgumentException exception;
        exception.execute();
    }
    catch (out_of_range) {
        NumberTooLargeException exception;
        exception.execute();
    }
    p_text.erase(0, ++(*position));                 // Side-effect.
    p_delimiter = p_text[0];                        // Side-effect.
    delete position;
    return integer;
}
/* Getter. */
int SortedArray::getFrom(int p_index) {
    int i = p_index;
    if (!(i < capacity)) {
        IndexOutOfBoundsException exception;
        exception.execute();
    }
    if (!(i < length)) {
        IndexOfEmptyFieldException exception;
        exception.execute();
    }
    return array[i];
}
/* Genereates ascending array of random unique integers. */
void SortedArray::generate() {
    //
}
/* Loads ascending array of random unique integers from a single-line .txt file. */
void SortedArray::loadFromFile(string& p_file_name) {
    string line;
    if (length) {
        ArrayAlreadyExistsException exception;
        exception.execute();
    }
    ifstream file;
    file.open(p_file_name);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        OpenFileFailureException exception;
        exception.execute();
    }
    if (file.eof()) {
        OpenedFileEmptyException exception;
        exception.execute();
    }
    getline(file, line);
    loadFromInput(line);
    file.close();
}
/* Loads ascending array of random unique integers from single-line keyboard input. */
void SortedArray::loadFromInput(string& p_line) {
    char delimiter;
    int index = 0;
    unsigned last = 16;
    if (length) {
        ArrayAlreadyExistsException exception;
        exception.execute();
    }
    p_line += " #";
    do {
        int number = readNumber(p_line, delimiter);
        array[index++] = number;
        length++;
    } while (delimiter != '#' && length < capacity); // Excess input is ignored (should it be reported?).
}
/* Counts the number of array accesses in the Multi-key sequential search algorithm. */
void TestRecord::MultiKeySequentialSearchTest() {
    int i = 0, j = 0, n = array.getLength(), m = sequence.getLength();
    while (i < n && j < m) {
        while (i < n && sequence.getFrom(j) > array.getFrom(i)) {
            accessed(); // array
//          accessed(); // sequence
            i++;
        }
        if (sequence.getFrom(j) == array.getFrom(i)) {
            accessed(); // array
//          accessed(); // sequence
            locations[j] = i;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
/* Counts the number of array accesses in the  Interpolation binary search algorithm. */
void TestRecord::InterpolationSearchTest() {
    int low = 0, high = array.getLength(), sequence_length = sequence.getLength();
    for (int j = 0; j < sequence_length; j++) {
        int key = sequence.getFrom(j), mid;
//      accessed(); // sequence
        while (low < high) {
            int array_low = array.getFrom(low), array_high = array.getFrom(high), array_mid;
            accessed(); // array
            accessed(); // array
            accessed(); // array
            mid = low + (high - low) * (key - array_low) / (array_high - array_low);
            array_mid = array.getFrom(mid);
            if (key == array_mid)
                continue; // Acknowledge that the key is found.
            else if (key < array_mid)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                low = mid + 1;
        }
        // Acknowledge that the key isn't found.
    }
}
```

I'm mostly concerned that `Exception` sub-classes aren't a good example of object-oriented design, as well as that my file/input readings aren't really safe.

Comment: Where's the contents of `main()`? This program doesn't do anything as presented...

Comment: @Barry `main()` will hold one massive `while(){...switch()...}` construct for a menu simulation (as I don't have neither time nor nerves for OO-menu implementation), so I'm saving it for later. Otherwise, it's straightforward - load from file/input/generator, test with `TestRecord`'s methods and print the number of accesses.
A possible refinement would be to count average accesses for successful and unsuccessful searches.

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't actually do anything, since `main()` has an empty body, but there are two major things worth pointing out here.

**Exceptions are thrown**

In C++, the way you use exceptions is to `throw` them. You have an out of range access?

```
throw std::out_of_range("invalid array access");
```

You have some generic runtime error? `throw std::runtime_error("some useful message here");` Don't simply log an error and `exit`, that is very much non-idiomatic. The C++ standard library comes with [a bunch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error) of different exception types. If you want to add your own, that's fine, just inherit from `std::exception` or `std::runtime_error` or whatever is appropriate, but when the occasion calls for an exception, `throw` it!

One other thing worth pointing out. In `getFrom()`, you perform two different checks. One against `capacity` and one against `length`. The latter is a good check, but the former is unnecessary. If `p_index` is larger than `length`, it's an invalid operation, full stop, and `capacity` will always be at least as large as length. The code you want is:

```
int SortedArray::getFrom(int index) {
    if (index < length) {
        return array[index];
    }
    else {
        throw std::out_of_range("invalid index in getFrom()");
    }
}
```

Note the removal of the unnecessary local variable `i` (you already get passed in the index, why copy it?) and the simplified check against bounds.

**Rule of Three/Five/Zero**

This is a big one. Anytime you need to write a destructor, you should write the copy constructor and copy assignment operator. With C++11, add in the move constructor and move assignment operator. The problem is:

```
SortedArray my_array(10); // allocated a new array of size 10
{
    SortedArray another_array = my_array; // copied the array
                                          // both SortedArray's hold the 
                                          // SAME pointer

} // another_array goes out of scope, so it deletes its array
  // which is the same array that my_array held... so that

// <== here, when my_array goes out of scope, it will try to
// delete array again. double free, corruption, BOOM
```

You will want to make sure that you write the copy constructor to actually do a deep copy of `array` so that this doesn't happen. Alternatively, make the class noncopyable by either.

Even better, just use `std::vector<int>` internally and let the compiler do all the work for you.

Comment: Agh, damned copy constructors. Professor would have my hide for that one. :D
I'm (We're) still new to C++ and we haven't quite got to learn about exceptions; the way that we are handling user-made errors are *report-and-abort* routine, simply to prevent data (and therefore result) corruption, so this is just my way of doing it in an uniformed fashion. You've been most helpful :)